Pandas get the row with a max field from a groupby result
I have the following dataframe:
col_a, col_b, col_c
1      01     34
1      02     23
1      03     567
1      04     425
2      01     234
2      02     54
2      03     56
3      01     56
3      02     567

I want to select the rows with the max value in col_b for each col_a value. I have tried this:
df[["col_a", "col_b", "col_c"]].groupby(["col_a", "col_b"]).max("col_b")

But I just get all values for "col_b".
How can achieve my goal?

df[df.groupby('col_a')['col_b'].idxmax()]

you should use groupby(["col_a"]) instead of groupby(["col_a", "col_b"])
